# How to Get Phone Contacts in Background Agent WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-agents

i am trying to sync the contacts to server after every 24 hours . so for that purpose  I am using background agent.
when I try to call contacts it does not get the contacts of the phone .
my code is here ...

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{        
   Contacts cons = new Contacts();

   //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
   cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

   //Start the asynchronous search.
   cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");

  #if DEBUG_AGENT
   ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  #endif    
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
  var a = e.Results;

  //  e.Results.Count();
  NotifyComplete();
}
```

can anybody let me know what is the issue or suggest a better way ....

Comment: Do you receive empty list or error?

Comment: there is no field called Count or anything in the e.result. but the is data in non public member but i dont know how to access non public data of the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get the result from the `SearchAsync` function:

```
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>( e.Results );
```